# Create a 3D matrix with the 3rd dimension being a random distribution

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, 3d, distribution

I am trying to create in MATLAB a 3D matrix (say, x,y,z). The x and y dimensions represent a 2D location (addressable by index x and y) and z should represent a vector containing random numbers of a normal distribution.

For example, if i were to extract the vector (3,5,z), it would give me all the random values in the z dimension at the location (3,5). x and y should both be of size 100 and z should be of size 1000.

Comment: How about `tmp = rand(100,100,1000)`. Executing something like `nums = tmp(3,5,:)` would return a 1 x 1 x 1000 matrix and you can execute `squeeze` on that to reduce the extra dimension

Comment: Where is your question different to "I want a random matrix of size [x y z]"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
z = 1:1000;
A = rand(100, 100, numel(z));
rvec = reshape(A(3, 5, z), [numel(z), 1]);
```

Here, rvec is the random vector you are looking for.

Comment: What's the point in defining `x` and `y`? Why don't you just do `A = rand(100, 100, 1000);`?? Seems rather wasteful don't you think?

Comment: Agreed. Editing it out.